# Consulta laravel sumar varios campos problemas con el metodo que utilizo

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

esta es mi consulta lo que quiero es sumarle al sueldo mi retroactivo y restarle la suma de todos los demas campos y almacenar el resultado en neto intente con sum()pero no me dio resultado o no lo estoy haciendo bien de antemano gracias por algun ejemplo o sugerencia

```
 $neto= \DB::table('planilla')
            ->select('planilla.id','planilla.vecinal','planilla.partido','planilla.ihss','planilla.isr','planilla.injupemp'
                ,'planilla.pp_injupen','planilla.ph_injupen','planilla.cooperativa','planilla.banco','planilla.educredito','planilla.colprofor'
                ,'planilla.colproin','planilla.sindicato','planilla.dias_inca','planilla.tipo_inca','planilla.incapacidad','planilla.reingreso'
                ,'planilla.otros','planilla.embargo','planilla.ficohsa','planilla.sueldo','planilla.retroactivo')
            ->where('planilla.id', '=', $id);
```

lo intente de esta forma con sum pero entiendo que sum solo suma un campo y toda su columna y no la fila

```
$neto= \DB::table('planilla')
            ->select('planilla.id')
            ->where('planilla.id', '=', $id)->sum('planilla.vecinal','+','planilla.partido','+','planilla.ihss','+','planilla.isr','+','planilla.injupemp'
                ,'+','planilla.pp_injupen','+','planilla.ph_injupen','+','planilla.cooperativa','+','planilla.banco','+','planilla.educredito','+','planilla.colprofor'
                ,'+','planilla.colproin','+','planilla.sindicato','+','planilla.dias_inca','+','planilla.tipo_inca','+','planilla.incapacidad','+','planilla.reingreso'
                ,'+','planilla.otros','+','planilla.embargo','+','planilla.ficohsa','+','planilla.retroactivo');
```

lo intente de esta forma y aqui si me funciona el problema es que no quiero estar traendo cada dato con una consulta diferente si no que todo me lo realice en una sola consulta

```
$vecinal= \DB::table('planilla')
            ->select('planilla.id')
            ->where('planilla.id', '=', $id)->sum('planilla.vecinal');

        $partido=\DB::table('planilla')
            ->select('planilla.id')
            ->where('planilla.id', '=', $id)->sum('planilla.partido');




            $neto=$vecinal+$partido;
```

Answer (score 1):

Con **sum()** solo se puede sumar un campo.

Debes utilizar otra estrategia, como por ejemplo crear un campo en la tabla que sea la suma de todos los campos que quieres sumar y realizar **sum()** de ese campo.

También puedes hacer esto:

```
    $camposSueldo = ['planilla.id','planilla.vecinal','planilla.partido','planilla.ihss','planilla.isr','planilla.injupemp'
                ,'planilla.pp_injupen','planilla.ph_injupen','planilla.cooperativa','planilla.banco','planilla.educredito','planilla.colprofor'
                ,'planilla.colproin','planilla.sindicato','planilla.dias_inca','planilla.tipo_inca','planilla.incapacidad','planilla.reingreso'
                ,'planilla.otros','planilla.embargo','planilla.ficohsa','planilla.sueldo','planilla.retroactivo'];

    $sueldo = 0;

    foreach ($camposSueldo as $campo) {
          $sueldo += \DB::table('planilla')
               ->select('planilla.id')
               ->where('planilla.id', '=', $id)->sum($campo);
    }

    echo $sueldo;
```